# Flutter MethodCall non-nil check in kotlin way

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, flutter-method-channel

I tried to make a MethodCall type judgement function using kotlin, but it return a type mismatch for me, how should I fix with it?

```
import java.util.Objects

import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodCall

class Utils private constructor() {
    companion object {
        fun getDoubleArgument(call: MethodCall, argument: String?): Double {
            return try {
                if (call.argument<Any>(argument) is Double) {
                    Objects.requireNonNull(call.argument<Double>(argument))!!  // The call.argument return Double? type, but when I add !! assert, it report Unnecessary non-null assertion (!!).
                } else if (call.argument<Any>(argument) is Long) {
                    val l = Objects.requireNonNull(call.argument<Long>(argument))
                    l!!.toDouble()
                } else if ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Flutter, so please excuse any errors.

You don't need `Objects.requireNonNull()` in Kotlin, because `!!` already does the exact same thing as `requireNonNull()`, except that it throws KotlinNullPointerException instead of NullPointerException. The reason it's not working is that Kotlin doesn't know that the Java method is guaranteed to return a non-null value.

```
class Utils private constructor() {
    companion object {
        fun getDoubleArgument(call: MethodCall, argument: String?): Double {
            return try {
                if (call.argument<Any>(argument) is Double) {
                    call.argument<Double>(argument)!!
                } else if (call.argument<Any>(argument) is Long) {
                    call.argument<Long>(argument)!!.toDouble()
                } else if ...
        }
```

It would be better to get the argument one time and using that value. Then you can rely on Kotlin smart-casting to simplify the code:

```
class Utils private constructor() {
    companion object {
        fun getDoubleArgument(call: MethodCall, argument: String?): Double {
            val arg = call.argument<Any>(argument)
            return try {
                if (arg is Double) {
                    arg
                } else if (arg is Long) {
                    arg.toDouble()
                } // ...
                else if (arg == null) {
                    0.0
                } else {
                    error("unsupported argument type")
                }
        }
```

You can use a `when` statement instead of a chain of `else if` to make it easier to read:

```
class Utils private constructor() {
    companion object {
        fun getDoubleArgument(call: MethodCall, argument: String?): Double {
            val arg = call.argument<Any>(argument)
            return try {
                when (arg) {
                    is Double -> arg
                    is Long -> arg.toDouble()
                    // ...
                    null -> 0.0
                    else -> error("unsupported argument type")
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Nice explanation and it works for me, tks.